# What's the point of REVEAL_TIMESTAMP and startingIndex in Bored Apes?

Tags: erc-721

These two variables seem to come up quite often in ERC-721 of all kinds, but e.g. in [Bored Apes](https://etherscan.io/address/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d#code) there is a `REVEAL_TIMESTAMP` and `startingIndex` variable.

However, there are only written and never read in that contract and I couldn't find documentation around them.

What's there usercase?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/the-elegance-of-the-nft-provenance-hash-solution-823b39f99473

Comment: Hi! Would you edit your answer to add the relevant informations? Using only a link is discouraged on StackExchange: if the link goes down, your answer is gone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).